# calling masterpage control from static method in pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a fileupload , in fileupload used onchange event , on change event use a javascript function that call a static webmethd to validate filecontent .
how can i calling masterpage control in this static function in this page
please help me this nessecery

Comment: show us the code what you're trying to do?

Comment: You may understand what you type here, but with out code, with out a real issue, with out details, we, the rest, can not help you, can not understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the static method has no knowledge of the current System.Web.UI.Page, you might not be able to access the property you are looking for. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without a code example.

You can try the code below, but it might not work since the view state will not be available via an async WebMethod call. View state is transmitted with each postback and a System.Web.UI.Page object is instantiated using the viewstate. Since you aren't doing a postback, view state is not available.You might have to do a full postback.

If the property is being stored in Session state or Application state you might be fine. Try

```
Page currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
currentPage.MasterPage.MyProperty = "foo";
```